# UnityEngine.Vector2 does not contian a definition for "Set".... using futile

Tags: c#, unity

I am a bit lost, I am using futile and I am just trying to run the demo. But I keep getting UnityEngine.Vector2 does not contian a definition for "Set" in just one class, my using statments are:

```
using System; 
using UnityEngine; 
using System.Collections; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

When I look at the documents, I see that Set is a function http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Vector2.html
I am using version 3.4.2 (in futile its happening in just the FAtlas class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the Unity docs are for the most recent released version only. The Set method was added in version 3.5.0*, which is why it isn't available in 3.4.2.

*based on the information at http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/40_history.html#3.5.0

Comment: thank you so much, is there any way I can upgrade to just 3.5? I don't know how well futile works with the latest release

Comment: oh never mind, found it